# npm i not installing updated/new dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I have npm version 5.0.3 installed.  When I run `npm i` it does not install updated dependencies.

For example if I first clone:

```
git clone git@github.com:superflycss/task-test.git
```

And then update the `superfly-css-pli` dependency to `@superflycss/pli:^1.0.0` and then run `npm i` the new `@superflycss/pli` package is not installed.  I have to install it manually by running `npm i --save-dev @superflycss/pli`.  Thoughts?

Comment: try downgrading the npm version < 5, looks like there are few bugs in the lastet npm module.

Comment: Indeed - Looks like I gained speed in general, but now a lot of things are manual :)

Comment: Posted a bug report here: https://npm.community/t/npm-is-installing-non-declared-root-dependencies/4761